# Angular 6- get rid of Input decorator limitations

Tags: angular5, angular2-template, angular-directive

Input decorator is used for communication from parent to child. This is what we write when in the parent component.

1.**ParentComponentCode**

```
<h1>Parent Component HTML part</h1>
 <app-child [childVariable] = "parentvariable"></app-child>


 //Parent.ts
 export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
 parentvariable = "Hello Child";
 constructor() { }    
 }
```

2.**ChildComponentCode**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-child',
 template: '<div>
          <h3>I am inside child component.</h3>
        </div>',     
})
 export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input() childVariable;
 constructor() { }    
 }
```

So in the above code we have used the child component directive in the parent component. That means in the parent component all the html content of the child template will be reflected as it is. That means the line  in the parent component, will give show the line           *I am inside child component.* in the console of parent component.
 So the output will be like this

> ## Parent Component HTML part
>
> #### I am inside child
>   component.

My question is can we follow any way so that we can use this @input decorator just for value passing from parent to child. 
In my code my child component html part is a very long and complicated code.
SO if i am use that child selector in the parent component the whole child component view is printed inside parent, which is not my goal.
 I just want to pass values from parent to child. help me out.

**alert-componet.html**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table *ngIf="tableShowFlag == true" [ngClass]="{'alertsidenav':tableFlag === true}" class="table table_view_land alertable">
        <!-- (matSortChange)='sortedData($event)' -->
        <!-- matSort (matSortChange)='sortData($event)' -->
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <!-- <th mat-sort-header="os">OS -->
            <th>OS
              <!-- <span>
                <img class="sortimg" src="assets/images/sort.png">
              </span> -->
            </th>
            <th>Host</th>
            <th>IP Address</th>
            <th>Domain</th>
            <th>Alerted</th>
            <th>Threat</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr (mouseleave)="flagArray[i] = true; classArray[i] = false;" *ngFor="let alert of filteredAlertData;let i = index;"
            [ngClass]="getSynchClass(alert.synched)">
            <td>
              <mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
            </td>
            <td> <img style="cursor:pointer;" class="iconclick" (click)="getDetailsOnAlert(alert.alertId); drawer.open(); tableFlag = true;"
                _ngcontent-c4="" src="../../assets/images/icon.png"></td>
            <td>{{alert.hostResponse.osname}}</td>
            <td>{{alert.hostResponse.hostName}}</td>
            <td>{{alert.hostResponse.primaryIPaddress}}</td>
            <td>{{alert.hostResponse.domain}}</td>
            <td>{{alert.reportedAtTimestamp | date : "short"}}</td>
            <td>
              <div class="buttonWrapper">
                <button mat-button class="btn btn-borderorg" style="top: 5px;" type="button">{{alert.sourceAsAlertType}}</button>
                <div [hidden]="flagArray[i]" class="box">
                  <a style="color: rgba(7, 123, 218, 0.952)">Contain</a>
                  <a style="color: rgba(7, 123, 218, 0.952)">Triage</a>
                  <a style="color: rgba(7, 123, 218, 0.952)">File Acq</a>
                  <a style="color: rgba(7, 123, 218, 0.952)">Acquistion</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <button (mouseenter)="classArray[i] = true; flagArray[i] = false" class="btn actionButton"
                  [ngClass]="{'setOpacity':classArray[i] === true}">
                  <img src="assets/images/dots.png">
                </button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

**alertdetails.html**

```
             <div class="caseDetailtab">
                 <div class="casedetailTable">
                    <table class="table table_view_land">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th><b>Scan Details</b></th>
                          <th></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>                            
                         <tr>
                          <td>Scanned Object</td>
                           <td>File</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
               </div>

                <div class="casedetailTable">
                    <table class="table table_view_land">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th><b>Malware Details</b></th>
                          <th></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>                             
                        <tr>
                          <td>Malware Type</td>
                           <td>Potentially unwanted program</td>
                        </tr>

                      </tbody>
                    </table>
               </div>


                  <div class="casedetailTable">
                    <table class="table table_view_land">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th><b>File Details</b></th>
                          <th></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Status</td>
                           <td>Alert</td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                          <td>File Path</td>
                           <td>C:\Folder1\Folder2\gg.exe</td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                          <td>MDS</td>
                           <td>F1wewe9232293ssmdsd32323</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>SHA1</td>
                           <td>F1wewe9232293ssmdsd32323</td>
                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                          <td>File Last Accesed</td>
                           <td>08/08/2018, 6:56 pm (PST</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
               </div>                     
         </div>
```

I want to pass the filteredAlertData from alertcomponent to alertdetails component using @input

Comment: A component is a "parent" only if it is loading the "child" element via its template. It  can be via explicit use of selecter (eg. <app-child>) or via <router-outlet>. The cause you are describing is, they don't seem to have the parent-child relationship. @input is specifically for transferring the data from parent to child. You can use services to communicate, though. Checkout angular docs for component communication between siblings.

Comment: they are having a parent-child relation. I have created alert and inside alert component the alertdetail component. I want to use @input but by using  <app-child> in parent. but for this the whole html of  <app-child> will be reflected in the parent view which i dont want.